# WebStorm unwanted indent in decorator parameter

Tags: formatting, webstorm

I'm trying to get our styling in sync between editors in our team to minimize conflicts in git, as well as getting a standardized style in our team. We are using **VSCode** and (various versions of) **WebStorm**.

I understand I won't be able to get both 100% in sync, but I just want to minimize conflicts/differences.

One particular frustrating thing WebStorm does is format the following:

```js
@Component({
   selector: 'test-component',
   templateUrl: './test-component.html'
})
```

to

```js
@Component({
               selector: 'test-component',
               templateUrl: './test-component.html'
           })
```

It does not cause git conflicts in this instance, but it's just very frustrating - and I cannot seem to find the setting for this.

> I have tried setting the scheme from **Project** to **Default (IDE)** and it formatted it correctly. However I changed some other settings and now I cannot seem to get that back (even when restoring defaults), and it is formatting like the above again.

Comment: I'm not JS/TS person, so it's not a full answer. But try this: 1) Select the code fragment in question (I've tried your code sample in an empty `.ts` file); 2) Hit `Ctrl+Shift+A` (or whatever you have got there for `Help | Find Action...`); 3) Type `code style` in search field or manually locate "Adjust code style settings"; 4) Invoke it. 5) You will see a popup with applicable code style settings -- try changing them. in my case it was `Wrapping & Braces | Method call arguments | Align when multiline` . https://postimg.cc/phmG8gr2

Comment: I'm happy to mark that as the answer, because the correct setting was indeed `Wrapping and Braces | Method (Function) call arguments | Align when multiline`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not JavaScript/TypeScript person so do not have any Angular projects around to test on real code.

I've tested this in a plain `.ts` file (which may provide different results to your actual code).

Anyway:

1. Select the code in question
2. Invoke `Help | Find Action...` (<kbd>Ctrl + Shift + A</kbd>  here on Windows using Default keymap).
3. Type `code style` in search box to locate `Adjust code style settings` entry.

   [image]
4. Invoke it .. and see what option would suit your needs. In my case it was a matter of disabling `Wrapping & Braces | Method call arguments | Align when multiline`.

   [image]

You can navigate to that option manually via the actual Settings/Preferences screen: `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript (or JavaScript)`